# Nodejs: Override global.eval

Tags: node.js, overriding, eval, nodejs-server, node-promisify

Is there any way to safely override eval? Have tried directly overriding:

```
var oldEval = global.eval;
global.eval = function(){
    // my logic
    global.a+=1;
    return oldEval.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

This somehow gives the following reference err:

**ReferenceError: createCallback is not defined**

**NOTE:** Error here is not generated while overriding, but rather on some occurrences of call to eval. In other cases this works exactly as expected.

Please find the issue reproduction code here: https://runkit.com/embed/8hv0yp94on8s

Comment: *on some occurrences of call to eval* Like what?

Comment: In case of rendering ejs, for example, eval is called, this throws the above stated error. The case can be observed in other 3rd party library such as koa-send.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of code in which a call to `eval` throws, so we have a [MCVE] to look at and debug? It might be as simple as returning the `oldEval` call

Comment: As stated, the problem observed is in case of some 3rd party libraries.
Following have been extracted from koa-ejs:

`(function readFile() {
var self = this
var len = arguments.length
var multiArgs = true
var lastType = typeof arguments[len - 1]
if (lastType === "function") return $$__fn__$$.apply(self, arguments)
var args = new Array(len + 1)
for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) args[i] = arguments[i]
var lastIndex = i
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
args[lastIndex] = createCallback(resolve, reject, multiArgs)
$$__fn__$$.apply(self, args)
})
})
`

Comment: Unfortunately, `eval` looks to be nowhere in there...

Comment: Sorry, my bad try reproducing with this:

`var fs = require('mz/fs')
 await fs.readFile('index', 'utf8');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202311/discussion-between-anupam-juniwal-and-certainperformance).

Comment: is there any issue related to scope of eval function? As eval runs in global scope.

Comment: yes @sumit_suthar it indeed is, on a lot of research, I came to the conclusion that monkey patching eval is not viable, this is because eval internally calls the interpreter and re constructs the lexical scope.